# Migration from DB2 to PostgreSQL-BLOB()/CLOB()

Tags: postgresql-9.2

Function in DB2: BLOB()/CLOB()

Criteria: 
Size of character string targeted for cast is more than 1GB

How can I migrate this function into PostgreSQL with above mention criteria.

Answer (score 0):

as i know each value is limited to 1GB. For larger content use module lo
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/lo.html